# react-native run-ios Build Failed with an error

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

The following build commands failed:

> /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/crumbz-gxjiljizwkskslfxfeyveayngkrh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeCouchbaseLite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ReactCBLiteRequestHandler.o /Users/apple/Documents/crumbz01-11/crumbzCouchBase/Crumbz/node_modules/react-native-couchbase-lite/ios/ReactCBLiteRequestHandler.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
> (1 failure)

Comment: What is the CPU of your Macbook? Is it a M1 MacBook?

Comment: It is MacBook Air. @Majidlotfinia

Comment: ```arch -x86_64 pod install``` run this to install pods